# problem with downloading videos that had same title in youtube playlist with pytube

Tags: python, pytube

In youtube playlist, if videos had same title, existing/downloaded video is replaced by the new video.

Example: a playlist consist 2 youtube videos  : A & A

First A isn't showing up in files because second A replaced first video.

I wanted solve this problem by renaming the file with a number before video title
Like this [A -> 1A] [A -> 2A]
Please someone tell me how do it.

Comment: Are you iterating over the `playlist` object? From the [docs](https://pytube.io/en/latest/user/playlist.html)
`for video in p.videos:
    video.streams.first().download()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are iterating over a `Playlist` object like so:

```
p = Playlist('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=41qgdwd3zAg&list=PLS1QulWo1RIaJECMeUT4LFwJ-ghgoSH6n')
for video in p.videos:
     video.streams.first().download()
```

Example from the [docs](https://pytube.io/en/latest/user/playlist.html).

Then the [download](https://pytube.io/en/latest/api.html#pytube.Stream.download) method takes an argument for `filename_prefix` where you can name the file yourself:

```
prefixes = {}

for video in p.videos:
    if video.title() in prefixes:
        video.streams.first().download(filename_prefix=str(prefixes[title]))
        prefixes[video.title()] += 1
    else:
        video.streams.first().download(filename_prefix='1')
        prefixes[video.title()] = 2
```

You could do something like this, however all of your videos would be prefixed with a number this way. You could add a suffix instead by using `filename=video().title() + str(suffix)`, because there is no `suffix` parameter on `download`.

Comment: I edited my answer to give you more what you are looking for.